# .NET 5 Identity provider for Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, identity

Can anyone point out if there are any good identity providers available for .NET 5 which support cosmos DB? (Except EF Core Identity Provider)

We built a couple of applications in .NET Core 3.1 and used Cosmos DB Provider for Entity Framework Core along with its Identity Provider package. It worked fine. But with .NET 5 upgrade, it no longer works correctly and gives multiple types of errors.

Is there any alternate Identity provider that can work with .NET 5 and Cosmos? We are using native cosmos DB SDK.

We just want to use User Management and Role Management features but dont want to write code for everything from scratch.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **[article](https://markjohnson.io/articles/asp-net-core-identity-without-entity-framework/) which I found replacing the Entity Framework Core of Asp.Net Core Identity** but provided the work around with SQL Server database.

I have gone through some Microsoft documents and few blogs but till now there is no success as I haven't found any identity providers for .Net5 - Cosmos DB without EF core but few identity providers like [Dapper](https://abhinandanaryal.info.np/article/setting-up-asp-identity-with-dapper) which is also a combination of EF Core identity provider only.

**One of the workaround available is [Using Cosmos DB as Identity Provider in ASP .NET Core 5 with EntityFramework Core](https://medium.com/geekculture/using-cosmos-db-as-identity-provider-in-asp-net-core-5-with-entityframework-core-4ce23be5c7cb)**

> We just want to use User Management and Role Management features but dont want to write code for everything from scratch.

**There is a Microsoft documentation that provides information about [custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity Version 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-5) where it provides the User and Role Management details and customizations.**

Comment: Thanks. This is really strange. Microsoft is pitching Cosmos DB as the next big thing and yet there is no solid Identity Management SDK built for it. I saw the article and code by Piero De Tomi. He has implemented the Identity provider using the custom storage provider approach but his implementation is incomplete. I guess the best way to go is to write custom code for identity or implement a full featured custom storage provider on Cosmos.

Comment: @UmerNawab I am using Piero's code and have also contributed to it, but his implementation is based on referencing data among containers which is more of a relational DB approach than an embedded or hybrid approach. e.g. the need for having a separate container for `UserRoles` while you can store roles of a user as `User.Roles` in a single container. I am exploring https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb right now, it seems more document DB oriented than the former. Let me know your thoughts as well.

Comment: I guess while you write your own implementation, you can specify the container in which to store the roles. If I remember correctly I tried to use codekoenig's implementation which had some issues with .net 5. Do keep us posted how it goes. Thanks.